# Excel: Create a named range based on text in first column

Tags: excel, vba

Hullo there.

I have a table of spare parts for different devices. Column A contains the device name, subsequent columns contain the details of the part. If a spare part is shared over a number of devices, all those devices are named in column A (for instance column A might red "Device A, Device B, Device C").

Is there a way to create a named range containing all the rows in which a particular device name appears in column A? (so for instance a named range containing the details of all spare parts for Device B?) It would need to be dynamic so if parts are added or removed for a device, the named range would update to reflect this.

Update: Sorry If I was a bit cryptic here, it's just that I can't include the actuial table as the data is sensitive. Here's a sample table to try and illustrate what I was asking:[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avegY.jpg)

So what I'm looking for is a way to create a named range for all the spare parts for Device B - ie rows 2, 3, 6, 8, 10. I'd want it to include any new parts for device B at the end or to accomodate it if we inserted a new part number 1235 in row 3. Hope that makes it a little clearer.

Comment: It is possible. You will have to use VBA.

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  You're asking "if there's a way?"  Yes, there likely *is* a way.  The best questions include code samples, but any ***specific,*** practical, answerable programming problem is welcome. Please see the [tour] as well as "[help/on-topic]" and also "[ask]". Also there's good tips [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question) and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in having a go at how I would do this. I ended up having to use a helper function.

I first did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to open the name manager and added a dynamic named range, `DeviceData` that captured all the device data excluding headers:

[image: Data and named range]

The RefersTo formula being:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1048576),COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1))
```

Then the following code in a standard module to generate the device named range groups:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateNameRanges()

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim arr()
    'DeviceData is a dynamic named range in sheet1

    With ws.Range("DeviceData").Columns(1)
        arr = .Value                             'change as appropriate

        Dim currValue As Long

        For currValue = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

            If Not dict.exists(arr(currValue, 1)) Then
                dict.Add arr(currValue, 1), .Cells(currValue).Row
            Else
                dict(arr(currValue, 1)) = dict(arr(currValue, 1)) & ":" & .Cells(currValue).Row
            End If

        Next currValue

        Dim key As Variant
        Dim rng As Range

        For Each key In dict.keys
            ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Replace$(key, Chr(32), vbNullString), RefersTo:=GetRowRange(ws, dict(key))
        Next key

    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetRowRange(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal dictkey As String) As Range

    Dim i As Long
    Dim unionRng As Range
    Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split(dictkey, ":")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
            Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, ws.Rows(arr(i)))
        Else
            Set unionRng = ws.Rows(arr(i))
        End If
    Next i

    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then Set GetRowRange = unionRng
End Function
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for this, I've not managed to get it to work. When I try to run it I get a message saying "Compile error: Type-Declaration character does not match declared data type" it then highlights the line "Public Function GetRowRange(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal dictkey As String) As Range" Any thoughts?

Comment: when the error occurs and the line is highlighted. Open the immediate window Ctrl + G and then put ?TypeName(ws)

Comment: What does is say? Then do ?TypeName(dictkey)  and presss enter and what does it say?

Comment: I have done an edit which might rectify the situation.

Comment: Hi there. I now get "Run-time error '1004': the syntax of this name isn't correct". It highlights the line: ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Replace$(key, Chr(32), vbNullString), RefersTo:=GetRowRange(ws, dict(key)) Sorry about this, I don't know enough to figure out the issue myself.

Comment: It might not like typed functions. If you remove the $ and just put Replace?

Comment: No change I'm afraid